Excluding SCS Module config based on environment?
We are keeping some test content synced between developer machines with an SCS module called.
Test.Content.module and would like this to go to the dev environment when we deploy there but not to UAT or PRD. The only exclusions I can see are supported in SCS are using the "rules": [] option or "excludedFields": [] to exclude specific fields in the module itself and ignoring based on a specific path.
Is there a way to exclude modules conditionally from the Sitecore.json file based on something like an environment variable or an Sitecore.developer.json file with different config or some other way?
I'd rather avoid having to pass Sitecore packages around. I know I could use an SCS item package perhaps - but it's going to be tricker to manage the content between machines if we need to add/remove items regularly from the package.

If you use an environment name in the module filename (Dev, Int, Tst, Prd, etc.) you could then make that dynamic in your process.

Thanks @MichaelWest, so like Dev.Content.module and Test.Content.module etc? but then in the Sitecore.json file would we replace the name of the included module dynamically in the build pipeline based on the env name perhaps?

Yeah, I would personally do Company.Content.Dev.module.json and Company.Content.Test.module.json then have a dynamic filter based on environment. I wouldn't think changing Sitecore.json is needed, just a dynamic variable used in the build pipeline.

Ok, yeah so just have Sitecore.json use pattern matching to include all the modules called Company.*.module ?

Yeah, you could probably get away with the patterns modules/**/*.module.json and modules/*.module.json.

I believe the only way to achieve would be through excluding the module names when running serialization push command, on the environment where you would not like to sync the items within the module.
dotnet sitecore ser push -e ModuleA ModuleB

Inside the push command you can provide the module name or tags for the module. You can find more details on the command options here.
Hope this helps!!!

Thanks. Yeah I thought about this but that means we need to update our deployment pipeline which is kind of annoying. It would be great to be able to have 'developer only configs' or something like an environment/role based attribute you can use as you can for Sitecore config files.

@AdamSeabridge ya we will need to use exclude option inside deplyment pipeline. On Unicorn configuration files, we used to use env based configuration to ensure this kind of requirement but I think on SCS this is a viable option.
